# Paginate error - grails dynamic scaffolding

Tags: grails, groovy

On looking for a solution for a two-domain-classes-in-one-view problem, I ran into the scaffolding tutorial for grails where I saw this:

```
class BookController {
   def scaffold = Book
   // overrides scaffolded action to return both authors and books
   def list = {
     [ "books" : Book.list(), "authors": Author.list() ]
     }
 }
```

And it says underneath:

```
All of this is what is known as "dynamic scaffolding" where the CRUD interface is generated dynamically at runtime.
```

I'm quite new to the scaffolding concept, and there is something I don't get here. I expect that the list.gsp is dynamically generated based on the controller return parameters, thus enabling me to have both lists in one view. I don't know if this is possible, it's just the thing that I expect to magically happen here. So please, correct me if I'm wrong.

If this should be the case, then something goes wrong in my application and I get:

```
 org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: Tag [paginate] is missing required attribute [total] at /customer/list:45
```

So this is something in the view, which I don't have, because I'm expecting it to get scaffolded. Could it be that the error is caused by the fact, that I use the default templates? Should I create a new template specially for my needs? Also, is there some aricle on grails lifecycle, so that I can see what gets passed when?

Thank you all for the help,
al

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have misunderstood that section of the Grails documentation.  By default, scaffolding provides an index, list, show, edit, save, update, and delete action.  However, when they Grails documentation says that you can return both Books and Authors, it doesn't mean that it will automatically scaffold a new view for BOTH books and authors.  It is saying that if you want to go and create a new 'list' view, i.e. `grails-app/views/book/list.gsp` you can make it so that the application will use your `list` closure and view instead of a scaffolded one.

Now, you've run into a bit of Grails trivia that I have never considered before.  What if you override a scaffolded closure without specifying a new view, will Grails give a 404 or will it use the scaffolded view?  It appears that it uses the scaffolded view.  As such, the default list view uses pagination, and it expects to see an `xxxInstanceListTotal` variable which the paginate tag then uses for its `total` attribute.  Since there's no value provided, paginate throws the exception seen there.

Scaffolding is pretty basic functionality, it's not smart enough to show a combined list of Books and Authors.

Comment: Scaffolding will use the overridden method - that's a nice trick. I often override only one `list` method to apply some restrictions.

Comment: I've almost expected that, it would have been too nice to be true :-)
@Victor
Can you, please, give an example for that?

Answer (score 1):

If you're scaffolding Book class, it will only scaffold list of `Book`s.

You can issue a command [`grails install-templates`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/install-templates.html) to see what scaffolding does. You can safely delete the src/template/scaffolding afterwards.

In your case, list.gsp template is expecting two variables: `bookInstanceList` and `bookInstanceTotal`. `bookInstanceTotal` is a value of required `total` parameter to `[paginate][2]` tag, so you get the mentioned error.

Comment: ok, thank you. I've already installed the templates, that's why I was suspicious when expecting both to be sent to the view :-)

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, in overriding the index() action so that I could sort the result differently, I found that in Grails 2.3.7, the default values are now `bookInstanceList` and `bookInstanceCount`.

[The documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/scaffolding.html) hasn't changed from `bookInstanceTotal`!

These names are further decided by the following setting in `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy`:

`grails.scaffolding.templates.domainSuffix = 'Instance'`